# resolve a java.util.ArrayList$SubList notSerializable Exception

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, rmi

I am using SubList function on an object of type List. The problem is that I am using RMI and because the java.util.ArrayList$SubList is implemented by a non-serializable class I got the Exception described above when I try to pass the resulting object to a remote function taking as an argument a List as well.
 I've seen that I should copy the resulting List to a new LinkedList or ArrayList and pass that.

Does anyone know a function that helps as to easily do that for this for example ?

```
List<String> list = originalList.subList(0, 10);
```

Comment: You can copy a list very easily. The ArrayList constructor will accept an existing collection (including your sublist) as an argument, and perform a copy.

Comment: @Afforess stole my answer.  Just copy it to a list you know is serializable.

Comment: Ok, thnaks this is what I've done using an ArrayList!!

Comment: @Afforess Why don't you post your comment as an answer? Then the OP can accept your answer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's because, List returned by subList() method is an instance of 'RandomAccessSubList' which is not serializable. Therefore you need to create a new ArrayList object from the list returned by the subList().

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(originalList.subList(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution was simply this code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(originalList.subList(0, 10));
```

Comment: The other proposed solution is better because it will pre-allocate the full size once, instead of possibly having to allocate the default size & then re-allocate space for the sublist while adding the elements.

Comment: If you care about performance you should not create twice the same sub-list